# Handle managed identity with JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, azure-load-testing

The scenario is that in Azure, managed identity is setup to the app and that would grant access to the API's.
We need to performance test the API's using Jmeter and run it in azure load test resource.

How to handle managed identity API's using JMeter?

Comment: Have you seen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-use-a-managed-identity?tabs=azure-portal? It seems like you can just add a managed identity to the Azure Load Test instance and then give that identity access

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of [providing a special HTTP Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/authentication-managed-identity-policy#use-managed-identity-and-set-header-manually) called [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) with the value of [`Bearer`](https://oauth.net/2/bearer-tokens/)  followed by the value of `msi-access-token`

In JMeter you can add this (and any other [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) if needed) using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager)

[image]